# Download a file from some parent directory

Tags: cakephp

I would like to download a file located in a parent directory of my application.

I want to download the file : /mydirectory/myfile.ext
My application is located : /www/app/

I've tried things like : `$this->Html->link('test','../../../mydirectory/myfile.ext')`
but it doesn't seem to work...

Is what I want to do even possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to download a file outside of CakePHP scope.
Before download, I simply copy the file in an accessible path, it's fast and safe imo.

I made a function dl() inside a Controller, when I call this function, I check if the file in the download directory doesn't exist or is different from the original file, then I copy the file in the download directory.
Then I can download the file whatever way I want

```
$SantVersionUrl = '/some/parent/path/file.zip';
$SantDlUrl = '/app/webroot/folder/file.zip';
$SantVersion = new File($SantVersionUrl);
$SantDL = new File($SantDlUrl);
if (!$SantDL->exists() || $SantVersion->md5(true) != $SantDL->md5(true)) {
   $SantVersion->copy($SantDlUrl,true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a symbolic link in your app's webroot to the directory you want to allow access to files from on your server:-

```
ln -s source_directory link_directory
```

This will provide access to the directory from the webroot.

You can then easily link to your files:-

```
echo $this->Html->link('test', 'link_directory/myfile.ext');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download a file outside of CakePHP application scope with a simple `a` tag, except if your server is able to serve such files (i.e. these files are accessible with a direct url such as `www.example.org/myfiles`).

But you can create an action that will download the file, it is quite simple:

```
public function download () {
    $this->response->file(
        '/mydirectory/myfile.ext',
        array('download' => true)
    );
    return $this->response ;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
I tried what you suggested, but my application is trying to download the specified file in the app/ directory, and it doesn't belong there, unfortunately...

Comment: If there where no protetction against that in `Response::file()`, and passing pathes like shown by the OP would work, you'd have a nice directory traversal vulnerability right there. Rule of thumb, never ever pass non-validated/sanitized user data to a function that reads/write from/to the filesystem! Imagine such paths would work and someone would do something like `?path=../config/app.php`!

Comment: @ndm You're right, but I did not want to add lots of stuff in my answer. I edited it with a hardcoded file path so that these kind of issues cannot happen.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to mention it, the main problem would have been that paths like the one shown by the OP would simply be rejected. Security wise, the `..` check in `Response::file()` should normally probably suffice to prevent the mentioned attacks, though I'd probably still add my own checks, just to make sure :)